# Kundera No Entity metadata found for the class

Tags: persistence.xml, kundera

I get an error "No Entity metadata found for the class" using Kundera a similiar
question is here,
[No Entity metadata found for the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087167/no-entity-metadata-found-for-the-class)
 but didn't find an answer (answer put META-INF into classes dir, didn't help me.

This is the error I get

```
3168 [main] WARN com.impetus.kundera.metadata.KunderaMetadataManager  - No Entity metadata found for the class class kundega.rules.Rule. Any CRUD operation on this entity will fail.If your entity is for RDBMS, make sure you put fully qualified entity class name under <class></class> tag in persistence.xml for RDBMS persistence unit. Returning null value.
Exception in thread "main" com.impetus.kundera.KunderaException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity object is invalid, operation failed. Please check previous log message for details
    at com.impetus.kundera.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:174)
    at kundega.rules.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity object is invalid, operation failed. Please check previous log message for details
    at com.impetus.kundera.graph.ObjectGraphBuilder.getNode(ObjectGraphBuilder.java:101)
    at com.impetus.kundera.graph.ObjectGraphBuilder.getObjectGraph(ObjectGraphBuilder.java:75)
    at com.impetus.kundera.persistence.PersistenceDelegator.persist(PersistenceDelegator.java:135)
    at com.impetus.kundera.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:168)
```

So here is my files.
**Persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">  
    <persistence-unit name="UNIT">      
        <provider>com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence</provider>
        <class>kundega.rules.Rule</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="kundera.client.lookup.class" value="com.impetus.client.rdbms.RDBMSClientFactory" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://130.230.141.228:3306/fastory" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="mysql" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>    
</persistence>
```

**Start of Entity class**

```
  @Entity
    @Table(name="eplrules", schema="fastory")
    public class Rule {
        @Id 
        //@GeneratedValue (strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column (name ="rule_id")
        private long ruleId;

        @Column (name ="rule")
        private String rule;
```

**Main class**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
        System.out.println("start");
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("UNIT");        

        Rule r = new Rule();
        r.setRuleId(103);
        r.setRuleName("SomeRuleName");
        r.setRule("SomeRule");

        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.persist(r);
        Query q = em.createQuery("select p from Rule p");
        List<Rule> rules = q.getResultList();
        em.close();
        System.out.println(rules);
        System.out.println("stop");

        em.close();
        emf.close();


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When I got this I checked:

```
 <class>package.name.DaoClass</class>
```

was defined in persistence.xml, this resolved the error. Also check

```
<property name="kundera.annotations.scan.package" value="package.name"/>
```

matches correctly to your package name.

Comment: your answer is very confusing

Answer (score 0):

"kundega.rules.Rule" package name is correct? Or is it "kundera.rules.Rule" ?

Comment: Yeah it's a spelling error, but It doesn't affect, because in persistence.xml I use the misspeled variant.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity object is invalid, operation failed. Please check previous log message for details
 This error can only be caused, if entity is invalid and not bind with persistence unit or you did not set field annotated with @Id

Comment: Also, validate your entity against https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Concepts#wiki-basic-rules